# Notepad++ delete text between 000 and next comma

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have:

> foo000,deleteme,bar
>   bar000,deleteme,foo

So in the find menu I can search for: "000," and I need to replace it with "000,--------" where the "-" remove the characters, so I end up with:

> foo000,bar
>   bar000,foo

The deleteme's are all the same length, (sidenote: I can't use "Alt + Shift + Left click" because the file is several million lines long so it crashes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture all non-comma characters after your entry ending in `000`:

**Find what:** `000,[^,]+`

**Replace with:** `000`

(Also make sure that you have selected **Search mode:** Regular expression.)